# How to sort by word length, then alphabetically, in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, sorting

I have this local JavaScript function to sort the way I'm describing:

```
const lines = ['foo', 'bing', 'world', 'baz', 'hello', 'bar', 'blank']
  .sort((a, b) => {
    const len = a.length - b.length
    if (len) return len

    return a.localeCompare(b)
  })
```

It will return:

```
['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'bing', 'blank, 'hello', 'world']
```

How do I forcefully sort the Google Sheet by a specific column (say column C), by length then alphabetically like this? Not a function which I plug into a cell, but like selecting the Sort A->Z option, how can I reorganize the sheet like this?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71149520/how-do-i-sort-data-in-google-sheets-by-word-length), which says:

```
=INDEX(SORT(A2:A; LEN(A2:A); 1))
```

But that will simply render the input in another column, which is not what I want. I want the whole spreadsheet to sort (every row) based on the specific column sort order as described.

Comment: This should be tagged [tag:google-apps-script] because the accepted answer instructs how to use Google Apps Script in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run a script before?
If not, open App Script in this menu: [image: App Script]
Paste the code there, save it and run it a first time to accept the permissions. I suggest you follow the instructions from 8:30 in this video: https://youtu.be/8RnOW4z7t2Q
After that when you open the spreadsheet again you'll have a personalized menu with that option ;)

```
 function onOpen() {
 var ui= SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
 ui.createMenu("Sort")
  .addItem("Sort Range", "sortRange")
  .addToUi() }

function sortRange() {

  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange()
  var array = range.getValues()
  array.sort((a, b) => { //first you order alphabetically by index 2 (which means ColC, you may change to the column you need)
      var xp = a[2];
      var yp = b[2];
      return xp == "" ? 2: yp == "" ? -2: xp == yp ? 0 :  xp < yp ? -1 : 1; //the first two conditions leave the empty cells at the bottom
    });

  array.sort((a, b) => { //then you order by length. You need to order in the reverse order of the conditions you want, first alphabetically, then length
      var xp = a[2].length;
      var yp = b[2].length;
      return xp == "" ? 2: yp == "" ? -2: xp == yp ? 0 :  xp < yp ? -1 : 1; //las dos primeras condiciones son para que mande los vacíos al final, en otros casos no van a hacer falta
    });
  
  //Logger.log(array)
  range.setValues(array)
}
```

Comment: Oh cool, thanks! Where do I put such a thing, and how do I use it (like how do I regularly sort again and again with it)?

Comment: How often do you need it?, every time you open?, do you want a menu to click when you need it?, or you need it each and every time you edit a value?

Comment: I want to run it occasionally after I add a few new values, maybe a menu or button would be nice.

Comment: I've edited the answer so you can have a personalized menu. Let me know if you can do it 

Comment: Hey @Lance , yesterday I saw a new question of yours and remembered this one. Could you make it work??

Comment: Alright I'm coming back to this finally! How do I create the app script and apply it to my spreadsheet? I am stuck there. I see how to create an app script (as per your screenshot), but not how to apply it to my spreadsheet.

Comment: Alright, I just had to refresh the spreadsheet page, and a "Sort" menu appeared up top. Now, how do I have it sort only the rows after the first (since the first row is locked)?

Comment: Alright I updated your code with the final solution I used, cheers! Thanks!

Comment: How do I find the sort function implementation later, I can't find it (but the dropdown button is still in my sheet!). I guess click on "Extensions > Apps Script"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may import the table as an array in the script (.getValues()), then adapt the formula you have pasted but changing "a.length - b.length" with "a[2]length - b[2].length", because C is the third column of the spreadsheet but index 2 of the array
Then you can .setValues(new_array) in the Spreadsheet
Tell me if you try it or maybe give some link and we can work it a little further!

Comment: How would I trigger it, do you have a working example perhaps :D

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).